# How many subsets are there that contain a specific set?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given a set $S=\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$, how do I find all subsets of size $k$ that contain the set $\{1, 2\}$?

I know that $\binom{n}{k}$ would give me all subsets of size $k$, but I can't seem to find a way to find just the ones that have that subset.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: If you know that it must contain $\{1,2\}$, then you have to choose elements from $\{3,4,\ldots,n\}$.  So choosing a subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ that contains $\{1,2\}$ is the same as choosing what?

Answer (score 1):

This is a more general/abstract discussion than the OP might be looking for, but sometimes a birds eye view gives more perspective.

Let $S$ be the [universal set](http://www.encyclopedia.com/computing/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/universal-set) for this discussion, containing exactly $n$ elements.

Let $A$ be a finite set containing exactly $2$ elements.

Let $B$ be any finite set containing exactly $k$ elements with $A \subset B$.

Of course $2 \le k \le n$.

The set $C = B - A$ contains exactly $k - 2$ elements and

$\tag 1 B = A \cup C$

$\tag 2 A \cap C = \emptyset$

It is easy to see that there is a $1:1$ correspondence

$\tag 3 B \leftarrow \rightarrow C$

So you want to count the subsets of $S$ with $k-2$ elements that are disjoint from $A$.

Hint: The place to look for elements that are not in $A$ is $S - A$.